# Storing forms configuration as document in nosql

Tags: php, json, forms, mariadb, nosql

I'm building a system ala google forms. A classic table schema in sql could be ok, but i'm considering other possibilities.

What are the solutions available to store forms configuration as JSON as documents in a nosql database, or in mariadb ?

Does the community has agreed on a json template for html forms configuration ?
Is there some popular bundles (symfony/zend) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON data type in [MySQL(>=5.7)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)/[MariaDB(>=10.0.16)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type/) or you can use MongoDB.
Actually there are a lot of options. The best choice depends on the details of your project.
For example you can use Symfony + Doctrine + Mongodb (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)

Comment: Yes, i saw that some versions of mysql/mariadb/postgres have these, but i'm looking for something a bit more elaborated like a php bundle to handle the form manipulation. The database is not a problem. Also a json template already elaborated would be great :D

Comment: @user1254498 You can use MongoDB in Symfony via Doctrine. Updated answer.